# HTML 5 audio - button feedback

Tags: html, button, click, html5-audio

I've written some code to provide audio feed back on a button using `html5 audio`.

It works fine when clicking slowly, but when clicking the button fast it has problems keeping up.

The problem I'm having is getting the sound to play as many times as the button is clicked,
my first thoughts are that the sound hasn't finished playing by the time the next click event is fired.

---

**How do I `stop` and `start` the mp3 again to ensure it is heard by the user?**

---

**HTML:**

```
<div id="count">0</div> 
<button>Click</button>
<audio class='mp3click' src='https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14037764/Development/jsfiddle/click2.mp3'></audio>
```

**Javascript:**

```
   var count = 0;
    $("button").click(function () {
        $(".mp3click").each(function () {
            this.play()
        });
        count++;
        $("#count").text(count);
        return false;
    });
```

**JsFiddle:**
You can see it in action here.
http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/ckUbL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/G8RYt/)

```
var count = 0;
$("button").click(function () {
    $(".mp3click").each(function () {
        this.pause()
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play()
    });
    count++;
    $("#count").text(count);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Great, thank you.. on a side note any idea why this does not work on Google Chrome on an iPad?

Comment: @Blowsie probably a one-off support issue. It is HTML5 :)